# android studio LG G3 not recognized as Android device

Tags: android-studio, lg

On Linux I'm using Android Studio 3.5.3 and SDK Plateform-tools 29.0.6
When I connect a LG G3, it's well see by the system

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 022: ID 18d1:4ee2 Google Inc. Nexus 4 (debug)
Bus 001 Device 021: ID 1004:631c LG Electronics, Inc. G2/Optimus Android Phone [MTP mode]
```

The first one is one Nexus5X in debug mode too.

*usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1004, idProduct=631c*
But neither adb nor android studio recognize it as an android studio.
Debugage is set on the LG G3 (connection UB: charge phone) 
Rescan devices from android studio report:

```
Found 1 Android device(s) ready for debugging:
```

* lge-nexus_5x-00fbff76a8659161

Found 6 USB device(s) not recognized as Android devices:

- LG Electronics, Inc. G2/Optimus Android Phone [MTP mode]

Any idea about this problem? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the solution here (https://www.verizonwireless.com/support/knowledge-base-113984/).
In fact LG G3 was not really in debug mode. To set it in debug mode, I had to switch off/on the "developer options" button, then I was able to specify "debug mode when USB is connected" :(
Now adb devices see it correctly.
Thanks